# CSS - Ajustar ancho de un elemento con padding

Tags: html, css

Tengo unos selectores para dar un ancho a los elementos de la página basados en porcentaje, el problema es que al dar un padding (que quiero que se mantenga fijo) a un determinado elemento, por ejemplo un input, esto afecta a su ancho, cosa que quiero evitar. Es decir que si a un elemento de asigno un selector para que tenga un ancho del 80% del total de su contenedor, no quiero que sea más ancho cuando le asigno un padding determinado. ¿Se puede controlar esto con CSS?

Imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es una simplificación del problema:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .w-10 { width: 100%; }
        .w-9 { width: 90%; }
        .w-8 { width: 80%; }

        .centered {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .input {
            display: block;

            /** el problema es el padding **/
            padding: 1em;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="w-8 centered bg-grey" style="background: grey; margin-top: 5%; padding-bottom: 1em">
        <input type="text" class="input centered w-8" placeholder="Elemento con padding..." style="margin-bottom: 1em;">

        <div class="centered w-8" style="background: white">
            <p>Ancho esperado...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aplica la propiedad `box-sizing: border-box` a tus elementos; esto hace que el padding, border, etc se tomen en cuenta en el calculo del tamaño total del elemento; de modo que no 'suman' al tamaño original.

Por lo general es recomendable aplicar esta propiedad a todos los elementos de tu documento; asi puedes mantener cierto nivel de consistencia entre todos al momento de tratar con `margin`, `padding`, etc; puesto que no tienes que preocuparte porque el elemento altere demasiado su comportamiento.

**Mas detalles aca:** [Box Sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

---

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    .w-10 {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .w-9 {
      width: 90%;
    }
    
    .w-8 {
      width: 80%;
    }
    
    .centered {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .input {
      display: block;
      /** el problema es el padding **/
      padding: 1em;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="w-8 centered bg-grey" style="background: grey; margin-top: 5%; padding-bottom: 1em">
    <input type="text" class="input centered w-8" placeholder="Elemento con padding..." style="margin-bottom: 1em;">

    <div class="centered w-8" style="background: white">
      <p>Ancho esperado...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow. Siempre meto un pequeño *reset* para los estilos con eso, y margin / padding a 0. Se me paso...

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes agregar: "`.w-8`" (tu class) y luego el "`input`" que afecta a todos los input con la clase "`w-8`", y darle un `padding` de `0` y hacerlo "importante" con "`!important`"

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    
        <style type="text/css">
            .w-10 { width: 100%; }
            .w-9 { width: 90%; }
            .w-8 { width: 80%; }
            .w-8 input { padding:0!important; } /** linea agregada **/
    
            .centered {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
    
            .input {
                display: block;
    
                /** el problema es el padding **/
                padding: 1em;
            }
    
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="w-8 centered bg-grey" style="background: grey; margin-top: 5%; padding-bottom: 1em">
            <input type="text" class="input centered w-8" placeholder="Elemento con padding..." style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
    
            <div class="centered w-8" style="background: white">
                <p>Ancho esperado...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sugeriría siempre evitar `!importat` a menos que no haya niguna otra solucion viable; el uso de `!important` lamentablemente puede ser problematico y es de cierta forma un *hack* para que una propiedad funcione; es mejor basarse en [Especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad)